# Firebase console is not showing updated data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing data to Firebase using the following code:

```
firebase.database().ref('cards/1').set({
  val:1
});
```

I then retrieve the data using the following code:

```
firebase.database().ref('cards/1').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.info('Getting value from database:')
  console.info(snapshot)
})
```

The code above works fine and is displaying correct result. However firebase console is not reflecting the update. I even tried logging out and back in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you writing a lot of data to firebase? did you see any non-realtime mode indicator on the console?

Comment: When you reload the app/page with the code you shared, does it show the updated value? If not, I recommend checking your JavaScript console for an error in the write operation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am writing very little data. Also as I've mentioned I can retrieve the new data from firebase, so the write operation succeeds, it is just not reflected in the console. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me either.

But to get latest logs, run this command in your terminal: `firebase functions:log`

You can see the updated logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my documents were not showing in Firebase Console.

According to the Usage and billing page:

> The resources available to you in the plans are capped. If your
>   project exceeds a limit, services may be disabled for that product.

After I upgraded, it started working again.

This could be because you have reached your daily quota. 
If you click on the 'billing and quota usage' link on your Usage Over Time you can check if you have reached your quota.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although I was using Firebase on Android. My issue was that for some reason, the SDK was providing me with an instance set in another location from the one I specified during the setup. To solve this, I had to provide the URL of the database, got the right reference from there, and the data was being updated.